# Is it possible to tunnel RTMFP through SOCKS v5?

Tags: socks-proxy

I am trying to access a website that uses the [Real-Time Media Flow Protocol (RTMFP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) in Firefox on Linux.

I need to use a SOCKS v5 proxy; it comes from `ssh -D`. Usual web browsing reveals that the proxy is working.

However, RTMFP connections don't seem to work (it keeps trying to connect and times out). Is it possible?